# Warning libstdc++-devel-4.4.4-13.el6.x86_64.rpm

Tags: linux, 64-bit, x86-64, redhat, rpm

im getting this error when trying to installing this rpm into the kernel server of 64bit.
The error is as the log below:

## rpm -ivh libstdc++-devel-4.4.4-13.el6.x86_64.rpm

warning: libstdc++-devel-4.4.4-13.el6.x86_64.rpm: Header V4 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 192a7d7d: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
        libstdc++(x86-64) = 4.4.4-13.el6 is needed by libstdc++-devel-4.4.4-13.el6.x86_64

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only install a RPM after you have installed all its dependencies.
To install this RPM first you need to install `libstdc++-4.4.4-13.el6.x86_64.rpm`

You can do this in two ways .

Method 1 :
Download and install `libstdc++-4.4.4-13.el6.x86_64.rpm` first and then `libstdc++-devel` afterwards.

```
wget ftp://ftp.pbone.net/mirror/ftp.scientificlinux.org/linux/scientific/6.0/x86_64/os/Packages/libstdc++-4.4.4-13.el6.x86_64.rpm
rpm -ivh libstdc++-4.4.4-13.el6.x86_64.rpm 
rpm -ivh libstdc++-4.4.4-13.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

Method 2 :
You can use `yum` to automatically resolve and install dependencies  for you

```
yum localinstall libstdc++-devel-4.4.4-13.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

If that doesn't work, try

```
yum install libstdc++-devel
```

Comment: I did try the command for the ftp server but it stating:
SIZE libstdc++-4.4.4-13.el6x86_64.rpm ... done.
==> PASV ... done.    ==> RETR libstdc++-4.4.4-13.el6x86_64.rpm ...
No such file “libstdc++-4.4.4-13.el6x86_64.rpm”.

I could not try yum command as I cant access rhel portal

Comment: If wget is not working for you. Download this link through your web browser -   ftp://ftp.pbone.net/mirror/ftp.scientificlinux.org/linux/scientific/6.0/x86_64/os/Packages/libstdc++-4.4.4-13.el6.x86_64.rpm

Comment: I did try get the rpm using the dowoad link you provide and it seems it does working. Thank you.